# How to identify SQL Server instances installed on local machine?

Tags: sql-server

I have sql server 2000, 2005 exress,  2005, 2008 installed on my machine i installed on my own so there is no truble form me to know which on is on which version. However i am finding it difficult when i browse verious installation on others machine which i have not installed.

Can some one please help me regarding how to identify the instances on local machine and what version they are on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're asking for, but if you can connect to the instance, you can run the query:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

which should give you the information you require.

Comment: Wow that helped.... but that is after we log into the sql ...... hot to identify the sql instances working on the machine ? ex machinename, machinename\sql2000 etc

Comment: @Anil Namde - where are you trying to do this from? Using what tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL Server Configuration Manager - it shows you information about the services for all local instances.  Go to Start > SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager